# Why is the past participle used to describe actions occurring in the present?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, participles, reading

Something I don't understand: why is the *past* participle used for describing actions in the present notwithstanding the name?

There are two forms of participle in English – present participle and past participle.
So, if one thinks logically, the present participle should be used to describe actions in the present (a 'grammatical present tense' as well as a real present reference), and the past participle for the past. 
But we use the past participle in some cases for describing actions in the **present**.

For example; *Chopsticks are **used** in China*.

We used past participle (**used**), but the reference is present. So shouldn't we use the present participle instead of the past participle here – it would seem to be more logical because the grammatical tense is present (present simple) and real tense is also present (that's what I think, though I'm not sure).

My question stems from a consideration of my native language (Russian). 
In Russian we have also parts of speech known as participles. But we separate them into *active voice participle* and *passive voice participle*. And then we further separate *active* and *passive voice participle* into *past* and *present participle*. And next we use the most suitable participle. So we don't have this problem in Russian.

For example: *The window was **broken***. (In my language, "broken" appears as the **passive participle in the past**)

Another: *The computer is **used** for calculating*. (In my language, "used" is the **passive participle in the present**, but it is **past participle** in English ... *why?* We use the present tense for 'computer is' (We use the computer regularly) so logically, we should here use the **present participle**.

I have one idea about it, but I'm not sure whether it's a sound analysis.

I've found that there is what is called a **passive participle** in English and it has the same form as the past participle, so if we're using correct terminology we would class this usage as utilising the  **passive participle**  and not the **past participle**.

We always use the passive participle in English when we use the passive voice. It is merely that the passive participle and the past participle always have the the same form in English.

Comment: Hello, Denis. I'll try to get back to tidy up your question, but I think it's basically a good one. On one level, in 'Chopsticks are used in China' 'used' is called the 'past participle' by most people because it's the same verb-form as that in  'Chopsticks were used in China', and, as there is always this correspondence, the name is only felicitous about half the time. _Why_ the same verb-form has come to be used in both usages is the interesting question.

Comment: The trouble is that English only has two participles: one active, present; and one passive, past. The reason they’re called this way is because they historically derived from present and past participles, respectively, even though especially the past participle is not used only in past-tense contexts in English now. It is also used to form passive constructions, which may be any tense or time, with all information about the time being provided by the auxiliary verb. It does still have some connection to pastness, though: a _broken window_ is a window which has already been broken.

Comment: Note that English is shown to be inferior to Russian at certain points. 'The window was broken' is ambiguous between the punctive and stative senses:  'The kitchen window was broken by a misdirected golf ball' and 'The kitchen window was broken, we discovered when we arrived back home'. // The term 'past participle' may on occasion be a misnomer, but it's the standard term for all usages.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet , Could I ask you something about more?
1. Past participle
2. Present participle
"Gone boy"; Does it mean a boy who has gone? (For example, 5min ago or 10 year ago)
Couldn't it mean a boy who is leaving right now?
And aslo
"Going boy" Does it mean only a boy who is leaving right now?
I think that principle of present and past participle should work there.
So if participle is  present participle then actions is being right now, if past then action has done already
Am I right?

Comment: @Denis A _gone boy_ (which is not very natural English, but understandable) can only mean a boy who has already gone. It cannot mean a boy who is currently leaving – that would be a _going boy_ (which is even more unnatural-sounding).

Comment: @Edwin [punctive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505719/why-is-the-past-participle-used-to-describe-actions-occurring-in-the-present)?

Comment: Relating to a point in time (in practical terms, a short time period) rather than to a period (durative / stative when things remain the same). It's synonymous with 'punctual' in this usage, but 'punctual' has the obvious usage which swamps this. 'The window was broken' may, without context, refer to the 'moment' it was hit by a brick say, or to the state the window was found / left / seen to be in.